# Como validar campo float en formulario

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, base-de-datos, laravel-5

Tengo una pregunta, la cosa es que estoy haciendo un registro, en el que los usuarios pueden introducir su peso, la cosa es que yo ahora mismo ese campo lo tengo en la BBDD como un *dato de tipo float* , y si un usuario me introduce *75.3*,*75.300*,*75.350* (Kilogramos) me lo introduce correctamente, el problema es el siguiente.

Si me introducen *75,500* o *75,3* **al introducir el peso, separado por la coma hace que me de error al registrar los usuarios**

```
SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'peso' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `pesos` (`peso`, `usuario_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (75,3, 2, 2019-08-29 19:49:18, 2019-08-29 19:49:18))
```

Os enseño un poco como tengo mis archivos:

**-Tabla pesos:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePesosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('pesos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');            
            $table->float('peso',8,3)->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('usuario_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('usuario_id')->references('id')->on('usuarios')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('usuarios_peso');
    }
}
```

**-Vista Formulario:**

```
<form action="/crear-1" method="POST" class="formulario-registro">

    <div class="container">
         <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                <label for="peso">Peso actual:</label>
                <input type="text" name="peso" placeholder="Introduce tu peso en kilogramos" class="form-control">
          </div>
     </div>

</form>
```

**-Controlador:**

```
public function postCreateStep1(Request $request)
        {   

        session()->get('key');

/*Primero validamos los datos*/
$data = $this->validate(request(),[
    'peso' => 'required',
]);

$usuario->pesos()->create([
            'peso' => $data['peso'],
]);

return redirect('/usuario');
```

Mi pregunta es, **podría de alguna manera hacer que se pueda introducir el peso separando los kilogramos, mediante "comas" o "puntos", en caso que no, podría hacer algun tipo de alerta, o mensaje de advertencia, para que hagan una correcta separacion mediante "comas", ya sea por html , script, o laravel?**

*Preferiblemente me gustaría poder guardar datos, tanto como separados por "," y "."*

Un saludo, y buenas noches!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes ocupar la expresion regular `/^(\d+(?:[\.]\d{1,3})?)$/` para que solo sean ingresados valores separados por punto, quedo limitado a 3 decimales por los ejemplos que pusiste.

```js
function validar() {
    var regex = /^(\d+(?:[\.]\d{1,3})?)$/
    if (regex.test(document.getElementById("myinput").value)) {
      console.log("bien");
      
    } else {
      console.log("error")
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myinput" value=""/>
<button id="testBtn" onclick=validar()>Validar</button>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @sioesi, por ejemplo,yo si quiero mostrar un mensajito al lado del input, o algo que se vea para el usuario, que podría usar para reemplazr el console.log?

Comment: Que validaciones estas ocupando en otros campos de tu formulario? Y respecto a marcar la respuesta, al lado izquierdo hay un ticket que esta plomo y debes hacer click para que quede verde al igual que si quieres dar un voto positivo/negativo hay unas flechas para arriba y abajo y debes marcarlas

Comment: gracias, ya me dí cuenta, edité, pero demasiado tarde, para las validaciones, uso *el validador de laravel*, y *el required en los inputs*, pero me gustaría dejar mensajitos personalizados, para algu tipo de campo, como por ejemplo , al peso, poner un mensajito si no introducen de forma correcta los campos, como podría hacerlo? no se como validarlos por este lado , hace muy poco que he vuelto a programar.